# How can I prevent Outlook 2007 and 2010 from disabling particular add-ins automatically?

Tags: outlook-2010, outlook-2007

Right now, we've got a business critical application that installs an Outlook add-in. It is a bit slow to load, which makes Outlook 2013 kill it after a few runs, but I've mitigated the issue of Outlook 2013 killing the add-in by using the Office 2013 Group Policy Administrative Templates "List of managed add-ins" policy.

I don't see a similar policy in the 2007/2010 templates, and have to remove the resiliency key from the user's profile whenever the key gets added for whatever reason. Is there a way that I can replicate the functionality of the 2013 policy for 2007 and 2010, or even disable resiliency entirely if granularity is not an option? If so, how?

I've found several ways to selectively kill the plugin-specific resiliency subkey automatically, but this still  requires the user to restart outlook if the plugin doesn't load because it was disabled automatically.

Comment: Have you already looked at this Technet article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179108.aspx - it shows how to handle it via GPO for Outlook 2010.

Comment: Yes. The issue isn't that the Add-in isn't trusted, or that it's being blocked due to security policy, it's that sometimes Outlook behaves in an unstable fashion and crashes, or the power goes off, or a user kills Outlook, or etc. and then Outlook adds the add-in to the resiliency key in HKCU, so the add-in can't be loaded until that key is deleted, even if it's trusted.

Comment: I cannot test this anymore, since we're using Office 365 now, but if https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3114305/how-to-use-the-windows-registry-to-prevent-outlook-2010-from-starting-in-safe-mode-after-it-crashes solves this for anyone, please let me know and I will post it as an answer.

Comment: you can post it as an answer and simply not accept it as the answer for your given issue (it will get upvoted as others find it useful), or if you are pretty certain it would have resolved it you can mark it as accepted as well.